# one node produced an error: Timeout was reached: [www.website.com] Connection timed out after 10001 milliseconds

Tags: r, web-scraping, parallel-processing, screen-scraping, rvest

I am trying to do web scraping using the following code and I am running into error.

```
table_desc<-function(links){descriptions<-read_html(link_to_stats_tables[links])%>%html_nodes("[class='content-footer']")%>%html_nodes('p')%>%html_text()}

cores=detectCores()
cl <- makeCluster(cores)
clusterExport(cl,c("%>%","read_html","html_nodes","html_table","html_text","table_desc"))
system.time(alltables<-parLapply(cl,1:length(link_to_stats_tables),table_desc))
stopCluster(cl)
```

It works fine when i try to scrape only few text, but we i run it on a larger scale, it is spitting out the following error.

```
Error in checkForRemoteErrors(val) : 
  one node produced an error: Timeout was reached: [www.website.com] Connection timed out after 10001 milliseconds
Timing stopped at: 0.09 0.14 4124
```

Can anyone help me with this please?

Comment: you are missing a brackt (`}`) at the end of the function. where should it go? Alos add all the non-base packages this uses. Also, should the `stopCkuster` line come after you create the cl object? You need to do a bit of work to make this example reproducible

Comment: I'd also recommend `clusterEvalQ(cl, { library(dplyr); library(xml2); })` (and any other libraries) instead of individual objects, as many functions have internal requirements in the package.

Comment: @RAB I have done all of those things you have mentioned. I just messed up copying it from my R env. I have corrected that typo here. But the problem is that It is functioning well until I start looping through larger number of url links. It even works for 2000 iterations, but not more than that. I have more than 17000 links to loop through.

Comment: @r2evans I am not sure how to make a reproducible code here because the code is working for small number of links. When i try to implement it on a larger scale, it spits out that error. I assume the owner of the website is limiting my iteration or something. Do i need to make my system to sleep for certain amount of time? like using sys.sleep()?

Comment: First, I think pummeling a single website in parallel as fast as you possibly can serves you well but might trigger them to throttle your connections. Since you are using `read_html`, that suggests they don't have formal API documentation, but do their terms of use indicate connection attempts? I know that if I detect a website of mine being blasted rapidly, I'll ban the IP temporarily and hope the perceived script-kiddie loses interest.

Comment: So what is the best solution for that? i am using a proxy server, but no luck yet.